# how to check whether the value of a string variable is Yes or No?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I check whether the value of a string variable is Yes or No?

```
<xsl:variable name="test1" select="DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test1']/DBE:String"/>
<xsl:variable name="test2" select="DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test2']/DBE:String"/>

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$test1 = 'Yes'>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="YES"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$test2 = 'Yes'>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Invalid"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test3']/DBE:String"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Please let me know what is wrong in the above.

Comment: Please edit your question, use the Code formatting (either indent code with 4 spaces per line or highlight and press the "101010" button to let it do it for you).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem isn't the `when` test, it's the `<xsl:apply-templates select="YES"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="Invalid"/>`. The `YES` and `Invalid` won't correspond to anything -- there's no concept of constants in XSL, and it doesn't look like an XPath expression -- so there's nothing to apply to.

Instead, try something like this:

```
<xsl:variable 
  name="test1" 
  select="DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test1']/DBE:String"
  />
<xsl:variable 
  name="test2" 
  select="DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test2']/DBE:String"
  />

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="lower-case($test1) = 'yes'>
    <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="."
      mode="test-yes"
      />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="lower-case($test2) = 'yes'>
    <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="."
      mode="test-invalid"
      />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test3']/DBE:String"
      />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="test-yes">
  Yes!!!
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="test-invalid">
  Invalid!!!
</xsl:template>
```

Also, keep in mind that variables can be "expensive" in XSL; the processing engine takes a full copy of the nodeset you're referencing, rather than just keeping a pointer, so you're carrying around the "weight" of the nodeset in memory while that part of the context is being processed. If you can do the test inline it's much better.

In fact, `choose` is relatively slow compared to the optimized flow of `apply-templates`.  Your processing will be much faster. If you can be **sure** that only one of the tests will match it would be better to do something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
  mode="test-yes"
  select="
    DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test1']/DBE:String[lower-case(.) = 'yes']
  " />

<xsl:apply-templates 
  mode="test-invalid"
  select="
    DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test2']/DBE:String[lower-case(.) = 'yes']
  " />

  <xsl:apply-templates 
  mode="test-otherwise"
  select="
    DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test2']/DBE:String
  " />

<xsl:template match="*" mode="test-yes">
  Yes!!!
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="test-invalid">
  Invalid!!!
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="test-otherwise">
  Something else!
</xsl:template>
```

If you can't be sure you can always add further tests "inline" to the `apply-templates`, for example:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
  mode="test-yes"
  select="
    DBE:OBJECT/DBE:ATTRIBUTE[
      @name='test1'
    ]/DBE:String[
      lower-case(.) = 'yes'
      and
      not(
        lower-case(../DBE:ATTRIBUTE[@name='test2']/DBE:String/text()) = 'yes'
      )
    ]
  " />
<!-- etc... -->
```

Comment: Also, you have a 0% accept rating. Don't forget to accept the answer that is most helpful to you by clicking on the check-mark to the left! :D

Comment: lower-case is giving error
ERROR:  'Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(lower-case, [step("self", -1)])'.
'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'

Comment: try `fn:lower-case()` - your xsl engine might require the namespace "fn" to understand which function to execute.

Answer (score 1):

The element:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="YES"/>
```

will attempt to find child elements of the current context whose qualified name is YES, i.e. it is looking for something like:

```
<YES ...>...</YES>
```

This is almost certainly not what you want. It's an easy mistake to make and I have made it frequently.